# RegEx for matching numeric and decimals in dataframe

Tags: r, regex, tidyr, data-manipulation

I have a column within a dataframe which has numbers followed with decimals which I want to remove to make it more tidy and sortable. How would i remove these numeric decimals?

```
a<-c("12. one", "1. blah", "189. hi")
b<-c(a,b,c)

df<-data.frame(a,b)
```

I want to remove the numbers and decimals that begin each variable in column a of this dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match one or more digits followed by a digit and any spaces from the start (`^`) of the string, replace with blank (`""`)

```
sub("^\\d+\\.\\s*", "", a)
#[1] "one"  "blah" "hi"
```

Or if the order of dots, numbers are different, then use the pattern to match 0 or more digits, dot followed by any space, replace with blank (`""`)

```
sub("^[0-9.]*\\s?", "", a)
```